spark dataset.filter chinese colname, org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException
I have a table with chinese colname 人员, use org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset to handle data.
When i filter with english colname ,is run success.
dataset.filter(" ( (name = 'name1') ) "), queryExecution is this:
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Filter ('name = name1)
+- Project [人员#541, name#542, 1 AS col1#547]
   +- Project [人员#541, name#542]
      +- Project [cast(人员#537 as string) AS 人员#541, cast(name#538 as string) AS name#542]
         +- Relation [人员#537,name#538] JDBCRelation(`test1111`) [numPartitions=1]

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
string, name: string, col1: int
Filter (name#542 = name1)
+- Project [人员#541, name#542, 1 AS col1#547]
   +- Project [人员#541, name#542]
      +- Project [cast(人员#537 as string) AS 人员#541, cast(name#538 as string) AS name#542]
         +- Relation [人员#537,name#538] JDBCRelation(`test1111`) [numPartitions=1]

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Project [人员#537, name#538, 1 AS col1#547]
+- Filter (isnotnull(name#538) AND (name#538 = name1))
   +- Relation [人员#537,name#538] JDBCRelation(`test1111`) [numPartitions=1]

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [人员#537, name#538, 1 AS col1#547]
+- *(1) Scan JDBCRelation(`test1111`) [numPartitions=1] [人员#537,name#538] PushedFilters: [*IsNotNull(name), *EqualTo(name,name1)], ReadSchema: struct<人员:string,name:string>


But if filter with chinese colname, is run fail.
dataset.filter(" ( (`人员` = '111') ) "), queryExecution is this:
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Filter ('人员 = 111)
+- Project [人员#576, name#577, 1 AS col1#582]
   +- Project [人员#576, name#577]
      +- Project [cast(人员#572 as string) AS 人员#576, cast(name#573 as string) AS name#577]
         +- Relation [人员#572,name#573] JDBCRelation(`test1111`) [numPartitions=1]

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
人员: string, name: string, col1: int
Filter (人员#576 = 111)
+- Project [人员#576, name#577, 1 AS col1#582]
   +- Project [人员#576, name#577]
      +- Project [cast(人员#572 as string) AS 人员#576, cast(name#573 as string) AS name#577]
         +- Relation [人员#572,name#573] JDBCRelation(`test1111`) [numPartitions=1]

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Project [人员#572, name#573, 1 AS col1#582]
+- Filter (isnotnull(人员#572) AND (人员#572 = 111))
   +- Relation [人员#572,name#573] JDBCRelation(`test1111`) [numPartitions=1]

== Physical Plan ==
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
Syntax error at or near '人'(line 1, pos 0)

== SQL ==
人员
^^^


spark version is 3.3.1
Dose anybody has idea?
I think it's not Unknown language UniversalChinese problem.
I have no idea.

You can use backquotes ` to quote Chinese field names.
SELECT * FROM table_name where `人员` = '111';



The filter has use backquotes to quote Chinese field names. dataset.filter(" ( (`人员` = '111') ) ")

And i try with spark version 3.0.3, it works.
